# overlay iframe over html5 video

Tags: html, video, iframe

I'm a newbye! Maybe a dumb question.

Is there a way show an iframe over a html5 video. I want to add some content over a video, like buttons, images etc.. (not play, stop buttons). I've found an example of how to add a images over video, but how to add more content? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `<video>` element can be styled just like most other HTML elements

So for example if you have an absolutely positioned video element

```
<video style='position:absolute; top:40px; left:40px; '></video>
```

You could place any other element over it, for example this absolutely positioned iframe

```
<iframe style='position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px;' src='/something.html'></iframe>
```

Working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4Y3u/

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I was looking for... and sorry for the newbye question!